# AWS SQS Approximate Age Of Oldest Message growing on empty queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs, cloudwatch-alarms

The title says it all.
Is it a AWS bug? We have alarm configured for this metrics and probably we will have to reconsider it.

[image]

[image]

UPD:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its probably not a bug. Do you have any messages in flight? i.e. not avaliable (as they are currently being handled) but stil in the queue.

Comment: Yes, the queue is pretty active, there's always something in flight, something in available. But still, there are no unprocessed messages

Comment: Ok, what I did - waited until I got nothing in available and in flight and purged the queue. Metrics was reset to 0 after that.